# Add Close button in Lightbox Bootstrap Modal Pop Up in Adobe Target

Tags: javascript, popup, bootstrap-modal, adobe, lightbox

```js
<script >
    // Lightbox
    var att_config = {
        // =========================== USER DEFINED CONFIGURATION ===========================
        // Use the main title to grab attention. Try to keep it under 40 characters!
        title: "Check out this great deal.",
        // The sub title should entice your customer. Keep it short and sweet under 80 characters.
        subtitle: "Here are more details about this deal, don't miss out on this great deal.",
        // Customize the link that closes the lightbox. Keep it under 30 characters.
        declineText: "NO THANKS",
        // Host your image and place a link to it here. The image should be clear and concise.
        // Try to keep the dimensions to 400px wide x 500px high.
        imageUrl: "https://patleeman.github.io/AdobeTT-Templates/images/AdobeStock_60946241.jpeg",
        // The button text should provide clear instructions. Keep it under 30 characters for maximum impact.
        buttonText: "GO HERE",
        // Once the customer has clicked, where do you want to redirect them?
        buttonLink: "https://www.adobe.com/marketing-cloud/target.html",
        // Time delay before the lightbox is shown, in seconds. Put a 0 to show the lightbox immediately, false to never show.
        delay: 2,
        // Set to true to close lightbox when the area outside the lightbox is clicked.
        clickBackgroundToClose: false
        // =========================== END USER DEFINED CONFIGURATION ===========================
    };
(function() {
    "use strict";
    var title = null != att_config.title && att_config.title ? att_config.title : "",
        subtitle = null != att_config.subtitle && att_config.subtitle ? att_config.subtitle : "",
        buttonText = null != att_config.buttonText && att_config.buttonText ? att_config.buttonText : "",
        buttonLink = null != att_config.buttonLink && att_config.buttonLink ? att_config.buttonLink : "",
        declineText = null != att_config.declineText && att_config.declineText ? att_config.declineText : "",
        template = '\n<div id="att_lightbox">\n  <div class="att_lightbox_background"></div>\n  <div class="att_popup">\n    <div class="att_lightbox_left">\n    </div>\n    <div class="att_lightbox_right">\n      <div class="att_lightbox_right_contents">\n        <h1 class="att_lightbox_header">' + title + '</h1>\n        <p class="att_lightbox_subhheader">' + subtitle + '</p>\n        <a href="' + buttonLink + '" class="att_lightbox_button" rel="nofollow noopener">' + buttonText + '</a>\n        <a id="att_lightbox_close" href="#">' + declineText + "</a>\n      </div>\n    </div>\n  </div>\n</div>\n",
        bgImage = null != att_config.imageUrl && att_config.imageUrl ? "background-image: url(" + att_config.imageUrl + ");" : "",
        style = "\n#att_lightbox {\n  display: none;\n  justify-content: center;\n  align-items: center;\n  position: fixed;\n  top: 0;\n  left: 0;\n  z-index: 1000;\n  width: 100vw;\n  height: 100vh;\n  margin: 0;\n  padding: 0;\n}\n.att_lightbox_background {\n  display: block;\n  position: fixed;\n  width: 100vw;\n  height: 100vh;\n  top: 0;\n  left: 0;\n  background-color: black;\n  opacity: 0.75;\n  z-index: 1000;\n  margin: 0;\n  padding: 0;\n}\n.att_popup * {\n  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;\n}\n.att_popup {\n  max-width: 800px;\n  max-height: 500px;\n  width: 100%;\n  height: 100%;\n  margin: 0;\n  padding: 0;\n  display: flex;\n  justify-content: center;\n  align-items: center;\n  flex-direction: row;\n  z-index: 1001;\n  border-radius: 1px;\n}\n.att_lightbox_left {\n  max-width: 540px;\n  width: 100%;\n  height: 100%;\n  background-color: white;\n  " + bgImage + "\n  background-size: auto 100%;\n  background-position: center;\n}\n.att_lightbox_right {\n  background-color: white;\n  display: block;\n  width: 100%;\n  height: 100%;\n  position: relative;\n}\n.att_lightbox_right_contents {\n  display: flex;\n  flex-direction: column;\n  justify-content: center;\n  align-items: center;\n  margin: 20px;\n  height: calc(100% - 40px);\n  width: calc(100% - 40px);\n}\n.att_lightbox_header {\n  text-align: center;\n  font-size: 32pt;\n  color: #221E1F;\n  margin: 0;\n  padding: 1rem;\n  line-height: 1.35;\n}\n.att_lightbox_subhheader {\n  font-size: 14pt;\n  text-align: center;\n  color: #221E1F;\n  line-height: 1.35;\n  margin: 20px 30px;\n  padding: 0;\n}\n.att_lightbox_button {\n  height: 42px;\n  width: auto;\n  min-width: 80%;\n  background-color: #4CAF50;\n  color: white;\n  border-radius: 2px;\n  text-decoration: none;\n  display: flex;\n  justify-content: center;\n  align-items: center;\n  font-size: 11pt;\n  margin: 10px;\n}\n.att_lightbox_button:hover {\n  background-color: #388E3C;\n  text-decoration: none;\n  cursor: pointer;\n}\n.att_lightbox_button:active {\n  background-color: #4CAF50;\n  text-decoration: none;\n  cursor: pointer;\n}\n.att_lightbox_button[disabled=disabled],\n.att_lightbox_button:disabled {\n  background-color: #D8D8D8;\n  text-decoration: none;\n}\n#att_lightbox_close {\n  font-size: 12pt;\n  color: #4A4A4A;\n  text-align: center;\n  text-decoration: none;\n  margin: 10px;\n  font-weight: 300;\n}\n#att_lightbox_close:hover {\n  text-decoration: underline;\n}\n@media (max-width: 801px) {\n  .att_popup {\n    margin: 20px;\n  }\n  .att_lightbox_left {\n    display: none\n  }\n}\n",
        handlers = function() {
            var t = null != att_config.delay && att_config.delay ? att_config.delay : 5;

            function n() {
                document.getElementById("att_lightbox").style.display = "none"
            }!1 !== att_config.delay && setTimeout(function() {
                att_config.fired || (document.getElementById("att_lightbox").style.display = "flex", att_config.fired = !0)
            }, 1e3 * t), document.getElementById("att_lightbox_close").addEventListener("click", function(t) {
                t.preventDefault(), n()
            }), document.querySelector(".att_lightbox_background").addEventListener("click", function(t) {
                att_config.clickBackgroundToClose && (t.preventDefault(), n())
            })
        };
    injector({
        template: template,
        style: style,
        handlers: handlers
    });
    "use strict";

    function injector(e) {
        var t = null != e.el && e.el ? e.el : document.body,
            l = document.createElement("div");
        e.templateClass && l.classList.add(e.templateClass), l.innerHTML = null != e.template && e.template ? e.template.replace(/(\r\n\t|\n|\r\t)/gm, "") : "", t.appendChild(l);
        var n = document.createElement("style");
        n.innerText = null != e.style && e.style ? e.style.replace(/(\r\n\t|\n|\r\t)/gm, "") : "", document.head.appendChild(n), null != e.handlers && "function" == typeof e.handlers && e.handlers()
    }
})(); 
</script
```

Hi, I am trying to create a pop up using lightbox template code provided in this link : https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/target-experience-templates/tree/master/lightbox
I have been able to do required customizations i.e. apply CSS , change text however, I need a close button to be present at top right corner instead of closing on background click. I tried many things but none of that seem to work. Can anyone please help? I am trying to create a button with class="close" and id=att_lightbox_Close

Any help is much appreciated. TIA!

Comment: How can we answer you question if you don't show us the relevant code segment?  Please edit your question and add in the code segments related to your question (as text -- not a link and not an image)

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. I have added the whole code. I beautified it but it is throwing error after that so pasting raw inline code as received in template.